# Heroku - Wordpress continuous GET requests

Tags: php, wordpress, heroku

My Heroku logs keep showing a "GET" request with the path of /wp-login.php that I'm guessing wordpress is attempting . I recently had this domain pointing to a wordpress blog but have since deleted the installation and configured it to work with Heroku. These GET requests are making so my app never sleeps and always runs out of the 18hr available time. Can someone help me figure out how to stop them?

```
2016-04-01T00:44:01.494679+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info code=H82 desc="Free app running time quota exhausted" method=GET path="/wp-login.php" host=xxxxxxxxx request_id=577a2394-dd63-4932-993d-559ddca6970c fwd="186.46.43.2" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

and another one:

```
2016-03-31T20:50:12.218290+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/wp-login.php" host=xxxxxxxx request_id=c7293679-8666-44e0-b970-adbb8252f2fe fwd="194.48.218.74" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=404 bytes=223
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your Heroku app using a free dyno type? If so, it will be forced to recharge after it exceeds a quota of 18 hours of activity during a 24 hour window. Heroku offers pay plans where your app won't shut down after 18 hours. You can also limit the amount of time it goes into recharge by scaling down the app . . .

A Heroku Dev Center page explains it all here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dyno-sleeping